# Splunk (perl) REGEX for DNS

Tags: regex, splunk

Im trying to create a regex to pull out the CNAME for DNS quires in splunk. I can get the first DNS name (everything after "CNAME-record for " and before ( "=" ), but i cant find an expression to get the next DNS name after the equals.

```
Mar  1 09:16:43 123.dns.local Mar  1 09:16:43 dns-01-1 SDNS: -> Answer: CNAME-record for dl.wu.ms.edgesuite.net = a26.ms.akamai.net
Mar  1 09:16:43 123.dns.local Mar  1 09:16:43 dns-01-1 SDNS: -> Answer: CNAME-record for dom.dl.wu.akadns.net = dl.wu.ms.edgesuite.net
Mar  1 09:16:43 123.dns.local Mar  1 09:16:43 dns-01-1 SDNS: -> Answer: CNAME-record for main.dl.wu.akadns.net = dom.dl.wu.akadns.net
Mar  1 09:16:43 123.dns.local Mar  1 09:16:43 dns-01-1 SDNS: -> Answer: CNAME-record for download.windowsupdate.nsatc.net = main.dl.wu.akadns.net
Mar  1 09:16:43 123.dns.local Mar  1 09:16:43 dns-01-1 SDNS: -> Answer: CNAME-record for download.windowsupdate.com = download.windowsupdate.nsatc.net
Mar  1 09:16:43 123.dns.local Mar  1 09:16:43 dns-01-1 SDNS: -> Answer: CNAME-record for dl.wu.ms.edgesuite.net = a26.ms.akamai.net
```

Comment: You should show us the regular expression you are trying so that we can see why it is failing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `=` in the data and the end-of-string anchor to add the needed structure:

```
/CNAME-record\sfor\s(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are some info after the second DNS, use this one:

```
/CNAME-record\sfor\s(\S+)\s*=\s*(\S+)/
```

where `\S+` means one or more non-space character.